# How to handle missing arguments in argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, default-arguments

I need to do the following:

1. `if` there weren't argument's for script variable `test == False`
2. `elif` there was argument `-t` or `--test` variable `test == True`
3. `else` there were another arguments get them as string and pass to third code

Now I got an error:

```
# ./cli something
usage: cli [-t]
cli: error: unrecognized arguments: something
```

My code for first 2 steps:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.test is True:
    intro = None
```

Comment: Never use `is` instead of `==` to test for equality: don't say `if args.test is True:` You can just say `if args.test`

Comment: What should belong to `-t` in the following case: `cli -t first second`? `first` and `second`?

Comment: You `if` conditions aren't clear.  Show us several intended usage cases, and what you want the `args` namespace to look like.

Comment: @smci. Always use `is` for singletons, like None. Agree with your second statement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within argparse you need that as a separate parameter, for example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('params', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.test is True:
    intro = None
elif args.params:
    pass  # process the params here
else:
    pass  # no params whatsoever
```